# Select Item Where Second Item With Condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following XML:

```
   <Test>
        <parent>
            <child>
                <Qualifier>S</Qualifier>
                <Number>11</Number>
            </child>
            <child>
                <Qualifier>S</Qualifier>
                <Number>12</Number>
            </child>
            <child>
                <Qualifier>B</Qualifier>
                <Number>3</Number>
            </child>
        </parent>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <parent>
            <child>
                <Qualifier>S</Qualifier>
                <Number>15</Number>
            </child>
            <child>
                <Qualifier>S</Qualifier>
                <Number>16</Number>
            </child>
            <child>
                <Qualifier>B</Qualifier>
                <Number>3</Number>
            </child>
        </parent>
    </Test>
```

I am reading this XML from my C# code.

There's an array of `Test`, inside it an array of `parent`, inside it an array of `child`.

I want to get the `Test` element, where the **second** `child` **with a Qualifier of** `S` **equals 12**

How do I use linQ to select an item Where **SECOND element with condition qualifier=="S"** equals 12?

I tried this:

```
   var test = Test.Where(e => e.parent.First().child[1].Qualifier == "S" &&
                        e.parent.First().child[1].Number == referenceNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I want something more dynamic because there will be scenarios where it's not the second element. So I will be using the linQ query on a wider broad.

Comment: Something like this: `testElements.Select(t => t.Parents[0].Children[1].Qualifier == "S");`

Comment: Cant you just select all that qualify with the condition, make it a list and use the index [1]?

Comment: @BotondBalázs This just gets the element, without checking the value. I want to get the full Test element with a condition on child -> number

Comment: @HelpASisterOut `testElements.Select(t => t.Parents[0].Children[1].Qualifier == "S" && t.Parents[0].Children[1].Number == 12)`

Comment: @EpicKip Check my edit. but I want to use it on a wider range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you load the above into similarly named classes:

Also assuming that the second child with S may not actually be Child[1]:

```
var test = Tests.Where(t => t.Parents.Count == 1 && t.Parents[0].Children.Select(c => c.Qualifier == "S").Count() >= 2)
.Where(t => t.Parents[0].Children.Where(c => c.Qualifier == "S").ElementAt(1).Number == 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tests.Select(x => x.Parents.Select(y => y.Childs.Select(z => z.Qualifier == "S" & z.Number == 12).Any()).Any())
```

Comment: Althought this code might solve the problem, it needs an explanation why/how this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the tests that a parent who has a second S Qualifier child with Number 12.

```
tests.Where(t => 
    t.Parents.Any(p => 
        p.Children.Where(c => c.Qualifier == "S")
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(cc => cc.Number)
            .FirstOrDefault() == 12)).ToList()
```